# what is the value of the expression involving bitwise operation in C++

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

On my machine, the following expression:-

```
int main()
{
    int q = 0b01110001;
    cout << q << endl;
    cout << (~q << 6);
}
```

prints the following :-

```
113
-7296
```

I have tried working it out assuming 16-bit integer, but my answer doesn't match the value obtained after the bitwise operations.

Is it simply a case of undefined behavior or am I missing something here?

Comment: `~q` inverts the bits, so the most significant bit gets inverted from 0 to 1. with signed integers, this makes it a negative number.

Comment: To add, the most significant bit is signed bit which controls either the value is positive or negative.

Comment: To add to add, `assuming 16-bit integer,` why do you assume that? Do `std::cout << sizeof(int)` and you will likely find that it is actually 32 or 64 bits.

Comment: This is why I try to only do bit manipulation on unsigned types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check binary representation of an integer using `bitset`.

**Program :**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int q = 0b01110001;
    cout << q << "\n";
    cout << bitset<(sizeof(int) * 8)>(q) << "\n";
    cout << ~q << "\n";
    cout << bitset<(sizeof(int) * 8)>(~q) << "\n";
    cout << (~q << 6) << "\n";
    cout << bitset<(sizeof(int) * 8)>(~q << 6) << "\n";
}
```

**Output :**

```
113
00000000000000000000000001110001
-114
11111111111111111111111110001110
-7296
11111111111111111110001110000000
```

As you can see, `~` inverts all the bits.

Comment: you were faster than me :P

Comment: you have to be quick next time, :P